# How to get callback data url into multiple select option with angularjs databind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to ask... 
how to callback data into multiple select options with angularjs databind

this is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("otobuus_app" , []);
            app.controller("index_controller", function($scope, $http){
                $scope.fetch = function(){
                    $scope._result_kota_asal = null;

                    angular.forEach(_result_kota_asal, (val, index) =>{
                            var _options = "";
                            angular.forEach(val.wilayahs, (val2) => {
                                _options += '<option value=" '+ val2.idWilayah +' ">' + val2.namaWilayah + '</option>';
                            });
                            var _opt_group = '<optgroup label=" '+ val.namaProvinsi +'" >' + _options + '</optgroup>';
                        $('#kotaAsal').append(_opt_group);
                    });

                    $http.get('http://dev.otodata.co.id:8181/mobile/kota/xxxxxxx')
                    .then (function successCallback (data) {
                        $scope._result_kota_asal = data;
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                };
</script>
```

This is HTML

```
                                   <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label col-xs-5">
                                            <input type="text" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="asal1" ng-click="fetch()">
                                            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for=""><p style="color: white;">Kota Asal</p></label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div id="asal2" class="col-xs-5 asal">
                                            <select class="kotaAsal" id="kotaAsal"  style="width: 200px;">
                                                <optgroup ng-repeat="list_kota in _result_kota_asal" label="@{{list_kota.namaProvinsi}}">
                                                    <option ng-repeat="wilayah in list_kota.wilayahs" value="@{{wilayah.idWilayah}}">
                                                        @{{wilayah.namaWilayah}}
                                                    </option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

and this is my data json from url: 'http://dev.otodata.co.id:8181/mobile/kota/xxxxxxx'

```
[
{
    "idProvinsi": 1,
    "namaProvinsi": "DKI Jakarta",
    "wilayahs": [
        {
            "idWilayah": 1,
            "namaWilayah": "Jakarta"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "idProvinsi": 2,
    "namaProvinsi": "Jawa Barat",
    "wilayahs": [
        {
            "idWilayah": 38,
            "namaWilayah": "Bandung"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 22,
            "namaWilayah": "Bekasi"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 2,
            "namaWilayah": "Bogor"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 17,
            "namaWilayah": "Depok"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 3,
            "namaWilayah": "Karawang"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 6,
            "namaWilayah": "Kuningan"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 26,
            "namaWilayah": "Purwakarta"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "idProvinsi": 3,
    "namaProvinsi": "Jawa Tengah",
    "wilayahs": [
        {
            "idWilayah": 32,
            "namaWilayah": "Batang"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 73,
            "namaWilayah": "Boyolali"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 29,
            "namaWilayah": "Demak"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 31,
            "namaWilayah": "Kendal"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 37,
            "namaWilayah": "Kudus"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 19,
            "namaWilayah": "Magelang"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 36,
            "namaWilayah": "Pati"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 35,
            "namaWilayah": "Rembang"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 74,
            "namaWilayah": "Salatiga"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 30,
            "namaWilayah": "Semarang"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 71,
            "namaWilayah": "Solo"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 72,
            "namaWilayah": "Sukoharjo"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 23,
            "namaWilayah": "Wonogiri"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "idProvinsi": 4,
    "namaProvinsi": "Jawa Timur",
    "wilayahs": [
        {
            "idWilayah": 49,
            "namaWilayah": "Jepara"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 75,
            "namaWilayah": "Pacitan"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 40,
            "namaWilayah": "Tuban"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "idProvinsi": 5,
    "namaProvinsi": "Banten",
    "wilayahs": [
        {
            "idWilayah": 39,
            "namaWilayah": "Banten"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 65,
            "namaWilayah": "Tangerang"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "idProvinsi": 13,
    "namaProvinsi": "Sumatera Selatan",
    "wilayahs": [
        {
            "idWilayah": 69,
            "namaWilayah": "Palembang"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "idProvinsi": 16,
    "namaProvinsi": "Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta",
    "wilayahs": [
        {
            "idWilayah": 18,
            "namaWilayah": "Wonosari"
        },
        {
            "idWilayah": 76,
            "namaWilayah": "Yogyakarta"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

data from the url has been entered and I checked in console, but not yet appear in select option. Please help me, thanks

Comment: I also use laravel in it

Comment: I tried your code and it works. The select option gets populated on click of input text box. If you want it populated even before that, then remove the relevant code from $scope.fetch() function and keep it out of the function. Also remove ng-click from the input textbox.

Comment: I've tried removing ng-click fetch and also scope.fetch, but there is an error in the angular.forEach part

ReferenceError: _result_kota_asal is not defined
    at m.$scope.fetch ((index):445)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14817), <anonymous>:4:206)
    at b (angular.js:15906)
    at e (angular.js:25885)
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17682)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:17782)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25890)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did and it works. I created a dummy json file for testing purposes.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="otobuus_app">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>AngularJS</title>
      <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
      </script>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
      <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"  ></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="index_controller">
                                       <div class="col-md-10">
                                            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label col-xs-5">
                                                <input type="text" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="asal1">
                                                <label class="mdl-textfield__label">Kota Asal</label>
                                            </div>

                                            <div id="asal2" class="col-xs-5 asal">
                                                <select class="kotaAsal" id="kotaAsal"  style="width: 200px;">
                                                    <optgroup ng-repeat="list_kota in _result_kota_asal" label="@{{list_kota.namaProvinsi}}">
                                                        <option ng-repeat="wilayah in list_kota.wilayahs" value="@{{wilayah.idWilayah}}">
                                                            @{{wilayah.namaWilayah}}
                                                        </option>
                                                    </optgroup>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>



        <script>

                var app = angular.module("otobuus_app" , []);
                app.controller("index_controller", function($scope, $http){
                //    $scope.fetch = function(){
                        $scope._result_kota_asal = null;



                        angular.forEach($scope._result_kota_asal, (val, index) =>{
                                var _options = "";
                                angular.forEach(val.wilayahs, (val2) => {
                                    _options += '<option value=" '+ val2.idWilayah +' ">' + val2.namaWilayah + '</option>';
                                });
                                var _opt_group = '<optgroup label=" '+ val.namaProvinsi +'" >' + _options + '</optgroup>';
                            $('#kotaAsal').append(_opt_group);
                        });

    //                    $http.get('http://dev.otodata.co.id:8181/mobile/kota/xxxxxxx')
    //                    .then (function successCallback (data) {
    //                        $scope._result_kota_asal = data;
    //                        console.log(data);
    //                    });


                $http.get('ang-select.json').success(function(data) { 
                    console.log("success!");
                    $scope._result_kota_asal = data;
                        console.log(data);
                });  

                 //   };

        });
        </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

And json file:

```
    [
    {
        "idProvinsi": 1,
        "namaProvinsi": "DKI Jakarta",
        "wilayahs": [
            {
                "idWilayah": 1,
                "namaWilayah": "Jakarta"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "idProvinsi": 2,
        "namaProvinsi": "Jawa Barat",
        "wilayahs": [
            {
                "idWilayah": 38,
                "namaWilayah": "Bandung"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 22,
                "namaWilayah": "Bekasi"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 2,
                "namaWilayah": "Bogor"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 17,
                "namaWilayah": "Depok"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 3,
                "namaWilayah": "Karawang"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 6,
                "namaWilayah": "Kuningan"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 26,
                "namaWilayah": "Purwakarta"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "idProvinsi": 3,
        "namaProvinsi": "Jawa Tengah",
        "wilayahs": [
            {
                "idWilayah": 32,
                "namaWilayah": "Batang"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 73,
                "namaWilayah": "Boyolali"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 29,
                "namaWilayah": "Demak"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 31,
                "namaWilayah": "Kendal"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 37,
                "namaWilayah": "Kudus"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 19,
                "namaWilayah": "Magelang"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 36,
                "namaWilayah": "Pati"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 35,
                "namaWilayah": "Rembang"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 74,
                "namaWilayah": "Salatiga"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 30,
                "namaWilayah": "Semarang"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 71,
                "namaWilayah": "Solo"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 72,
                "namaWilayah": "Sukoharjo"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 23,
                "namaWilayah": "Wonogiri"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "idProvinsi": 4,
        "namaProvinsi": "Jawa Timur",
        "wilayahs": [
            {
                "idWilayah": 49,
                "namaWilayah": "Jepara"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 75,
                "namaWilayah": "Pacitan"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 40,
                "namaWilayah": "Tuban"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "idProvinsi": 5,
        "namaProvinsi": "Banten",
        "wilayahs": [
            {
                "idWilayah": 39,
                "namaWilayah": "Banten"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 65,
                "namaWilayah": "Tangerang"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "idProvinsi": 13,
        "namaProvinsi": "Sumatera Selatan",
        "wilayahs": [
            {
                "idWilayah": 69,
                "namaWilayah": "Palembang"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "idProvinsi": 16,
        "namaProvinsi": "Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta",
        "wilayahs": [
            {
                "idWilayah": 18,
                "namaWilayah": "Wonosari"
            },
            {
                "idWilayah": 76,
                "namaWilayah": "Yogyakarta"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

Comment: that's work... thanks. but if I want to create data select with chosen jquery, how to do?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to accomplish. Tell me more what you want to do.

Comment: so the first time I create data select with chosen jquery, then I do input data API with angularjs ... if the data API in GET with hardcode (without http request), the data appear smoothly. but when the data is invoked with http request, chosen jquery suddenly does not work. is chosen jquery can not be used when http request works?